# BeautifulSoup : TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's my code :

```
v_card = soup.find('div', {'class':'col subgroup vcard'})
if v_card is not None :
    print v_card.prettify()
    infos = v_card.findAll('li')
    print infos[0].text()
```

Here's the output :

```
<div class="col subgroup vcard">
<ul>
 <li>
  infos I need to get
 </li>
 <li>
  infos I need to get
 </li>
 <li>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xxxx.py", line 43, in <module>
    print infos[0].text()
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Note that if I remove the `.text()` method, then it prints successfully the `<li>` tag and its content.

This is weird because with other elements I have no problem using `.text()`, I don't get it, any explanations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.text` is an attribute, returning the contained text of the node. It is not callable, just use it directly:

```
print infos[0].text
```

You may have gotten confused with the [`Element.get_text()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) here; accessing the `.text` attribute is basically the same thing as calling `.get_text()` without any arguments.

Comment: Doh, stupid mistake that could have kept me wondering for ever...
Thanks man.