# Python BeautifulSoup: Loop through elements to strip whitespace from within a function

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a function that I can reuse to strip whitespace from scraped elements. I am scraping `h2`, `li` and `p` tags; they are currently being returned as `<tag>    string    </tag>` and I'd like to remove the whitespace and save the content back using `*.get_text(strip=True)`.

`h_content = soup.select('h2')` will store all the `h2` tags found.

`p_content = soup.select('p')` will store all the `p` tags found.

And so on.

I have been trying this but am not sure how to return the items to the original location, that is to say, return them here --> `*_content`

```
def remove_whitespace(tags):
    for item in tags:
        item.get_text(strip=True)
        return item
```

The ideal situation is to end up with a function that I can reuse.

`remove_whitespace(*_content)`

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: When I place return inside of the loop and execute p_content = remove_whitespace(p_content) I see that the function worked but only in the first item and when I place return outside of the loop and execute again I receive an error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> \ File "<stdin>", line 3, in remove_whitespace \ AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

Comment: Are you trying to modify the HTML and save a version with whitespace removed? Can you [edit] your question to give some worked example

Comment: Yes @MartinEvans that is what I am trying to do. I've edited my question and hopefully it is a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_text'

stems from an element (`Tag`) in given result set, that is not an instance or descendant of class `NavigableString`. As such it has no method `get_text`.

See also docs [Miscellaneous](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous) common errors.

I would suggest to use the [*string-generators*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string-generators) like `stripped_strings` or the simple `text` attribute:

```
def remove_whitespace(tags):
    texts = [] 
    for t in tags:
        print(t, type(t))  # debug print to see the type
        texts.append(t.text.strip())
    return texts
```

See also:

- ['unicode' object has no attribute 'prettify'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325533/unicode-object-has-no-attribute-prettify)
- [How to make BeautifulSoup 'replace_with' attribute work with a 'unicode' object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023173/how-to-make-beautifulsoup-replace-with-attribute-work-with-a-unicode-object)
- [BeautifulSoup : TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844567/beautifulsoup-typeerror-unicode-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: This worked and it helped me find out the reason for my `AttributeError` as well. One thing I can't seem to understand clearly is how `texts = []` is storing the results in the function but when I do `print(p_content)` I see the cleaned up results. How is the list `res` mapping back to `p_content`?

Answer (score 1):

Using "return" exits the function after the first iteration. You need to do something like this to stop that from happening:

```
def remove_whitespace(tags):
    res=[]
    for item in tags:
        res.append(item.get_text(strip=True))
    return res
```

Comment: The collect into list and return list is a good step. However, I am not sure that this will solve the current error with BS `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get_text'.

Comment: @hc_dev I went back through my logout output and realized that somewhere through all my trial and errors I had a stored instance of `p_content` that I had cleaned up and stored as `u'one item'` and that is why I was getting the `AttributeError`.